# A class imported from a companion not usable as the constructor parameter default value

Tags: scala, companion-object

Consider following code:

```
object Main extends App {
  object Project {
    case class Config(rules: Seq[String] = Seq.empty)
  }

  import Project._

  //case class Project(root: String, config: Config) // compiles fine

  //case class Project(root: String, config: Project.Config = Project.Config()) // compiles fine

  case class Project(root: String, config: Config = Config()) // error: not found: type Config

}
```

Why does the last version not compile (same with `Config = Config.apply()`)?

Comment: It looks like a bug to me.

Comment: It probably has to do with the fact that `case class`es add some code in their companion object, so they have trouble accessing it before they are properly defined. However, you can access (implicitly defined) `Project.apply` in `Project` constructor, so it really looks weird to me.

Comment: When I place companion object after the case class, it works.

Comment: Note: There was an issue with local case classes, where you need to place companion before the case class - see [Scala: order of definition for companion object vs case class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590665/scala-order-of-definition-for-companion-object-vs-case-class)

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear to me if this is a bug or not, but here is why it produces an error:

Consider this, which works:

```
import Project._

object Project {
  case class Config()
}

case class Project(config: Config = Config())
```

When you add a default argument the compiler generates a method to calculate the value.  When that value is a constructor default, that method is added to the companion object of the class.  So the compiler will generate this method:

```
def <init>$default$1: Project.Config = Config()
```

Which will get added to your `Project` object.

The Scala type checker generates an object tree of [`Contexts`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/96a7617eb6c90f8891eb39f20a7f41a745a8e195/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Contexts.scala#L187).  Each context has a reference to the context of it's outer scope.  So the generated method gets a context and that generated method's outer scope is the `Project` companion object.

When the type checker attempts to resolve `Config()` it traverses all the enclosing contexts and cannot find `Config` (I am not sure why, and this may be a bug).

Once it has exhausted the contexts it resolves the imports which has the import `Project._`!  The type checker is happy because it can now traverse the imports and find the apply method.

Now when you move the import below `Project`:

```
object Project {
  case class Config()
}

import Project._

case class Project(config: Config = Config())
```

In this case the imports available to the generated method does not have the `Project._` import (this may also be a bug), I'm assuming because it's below the object definition which is where the generated method lives.  The type checker then throws an error because it can't find `Config`.

What appears to be happening is when the type checker is resolving `Config()` it needs the import above the `Project` companion object as it needs to process the import to be able to resolve it and unless the import is above `Project` that import is *not* in scope.

For those who wish to debug further take a look at [`Contexts.lookupSymbol`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/96a7617eb6c90f8891eb39f20a7f41a745a8e195/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Contexts.scala#L994) which is where the lookup is happening

Comment: Placing import before the companion provides a nice (even if a bit strange) workaround.